# Firebase indexing for the same duplicate field in mutiple user documents

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a booking calendar for users in firestore but do not want to creat an index for each users event "_timeStamp" field and "_service".

Path /_sharedData/_calendars/userID/eventID

```
var cal = db.collection("sharedData").doc("calendars").collection(userID);

var query = cal.where("_service", "==", _myService)
.where("_timeStamp", ">", _dStart)
.where("_timeStamp", "<", _dEnd)
.limit(200)
.get()
```

The only work round way I can see this being pratical is if I put all user events into the same collection removing userID, then querying it, but I may hit the 1mb collection limit.

Path /_calendars/eventID

```
var cal = db.collection("calendars");

var query = cal.where("_userID", "==", _myUser)
.where("_service", "==", _myService)
.where("_timeStamp", ">", _dStart)
.where("_timeStamp", "<", _dEnd)
.limit(200)
.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what that 1MB limit is about.  The only [documented limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) of 1MB applies to the maximum size of a single document.  You can have a virtually unlimited number of documents in a collection, and you can query them all efficiently as long as you've created an index.  Your second approach should be fine.